# openhardware monitor exception

Tags: c#, exception, ddl, openhardwaremonitor

My program is giving me two exceptions when running open ().

I already did a lot of search and I could not solve it.
Someone can help me please, I am enthusiastic in programming. So, I do not know very well to solve these errors.

```
public void tempcpu()
{
    myComputer = new Computer()
    {
        MainboardEnabled = true,
        CPUEnabled = true,
        RAMEnabled = true,
        GPUEnabled = true,
        FanControllerEnabled = true,
        HDDEnabled = true
    };
    myComputer.Open();

    float averange = 0;
    foreach (var hardware in myComputer.Hardware)
    {
        if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
        {
            hardware.Update();
            foreach (var sensor in (hardware.Sensors))enter code here
                if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                {if(sensor.Value!= null)
          averange = averange + sensor.Value.Value;
                }
             }
        cpu = averange / 5;
        myComputer.Close();
    }
}
```

Exceptions :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are in the images below

Comment: In which line of code this exceptions occurs?

Comment: mycomputer.open();

Comment: Interesting. What type is myComputer? What is Computer type? Show full path with all namespaces.

Comment: Computer myComputer;

Comment: ;-) but what is Computer

Comment: Computer --> Class openhardwaremonitor.hardware.Computer

Comment: This is opensource so you can download code and debug why open fails. Mayby some bad parameters.

Comment: After all how exceptions are thrown non CPUENABLE = true;

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `myComputer.Close();` from your `foreach` loop and put if afterwards. You're closing `myComputer` after the first iteration of your loop and then trying to access it again, hence your `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Also not sure if its a typo or if it's part of your code, but you shouldn't have `enter code here` in the middle of your method :-)

Comment: I already removed the close () and still gives the same error.

It returns as exceptions in mycomputer.open ();

Comment: Did you remove it completely or just from the `foreach` loop?

Comment: just from the foreach loop

Comment: After all how exceptions are thrown non CPU ENABLE = true;